# Centering custom marker GMSMapView

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps

I am trying to position my custom marker in iOS(Objective-C) with Google Maps.

Map view is all showing up fine with marker, however, moving the map will take the marker with it as its fetching current location. What I am looking for is the have it set to center of the map container, which will then fetch coordinates of map pin and display in search bar.

I am thinking I am doing this in reverse? I added the customer marker as a UIImage of the map container however it still does not show. Should I be getting the location from the position of the map marker, and then reverse geocoding address from there.

```
- (void)addPins:(float)lat andLng:(float)lng andName:(NSString*)strName withAddress:(NSString*)strAddr
{
    // Creates a marker in the center of the map.
    GMSMarker *marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
    marker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(currentUserLocation.coordinate.latitude, currentUserLocation.coordinate.longitude);

    NSLog(@"lat : %f, lng : %f", lat, lng);

    marker.icon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"map_pin"];
    marker.title = strName;
    marker.snippet = strAddr;
    marker.appearAnimation = kGMSMarkerAnimationPop;
    marker.map = mapView;
}
```

The user needs to be able to search and set their address, besides their current location.

Thanks

Comment: My answer helped you or not ? Reply to me

Answer (score 0):

Use your mapView delegate and use the responder to re-center your pin and re-fire your geocoordinate lookup.

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionWillChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView regionDidChangeAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

Edit: If GMS Maps does not have these delegates, the approach may work with using whatever `[mapView didUpdate]`callback they have documented.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `GMSCameraPosition` for centering your marker

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:"YOUR LATITUDE"
                                                                longitude:"YOUR LONGITUDE"
                                                                     zoom:centerZoom];

"YOUT GMSMAPVIEW" = [GMSMapView mapWithFrame:"YOUR VIEW".bounds camera:camera];
```

Comment: Hmm the UIImage is not showing at all, only on current location. Is it best to just use the image "map_pin" on top of the map container, as this would then let a user not allowing location to also set an address?

Comment: When your app runs, this will lead you to your marker pin and after this you can set pin anywhere into map for getting location or you can use Draggableannotationview for dragging your marker position